# Jquery mouseover and z-index on overlapping elements (Chrome)

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I'm using bootstrap with a fluid grid, which make the elements overlap a bit, when I hover over each element its border gets highlighted, by way of:

`.on('mouseover')` then apply:

```
$(this).css({ 'border': 'black', 
              'border-style': 'solid',
              'border-width': '3px',
              'z-index': 9999});
```

and:

`.on('mouseleave')` do:

```
$(this).css({ 'border': 'none',
             'z-index': 111});
```

This does get applied on the elements, but I doesn't have any effect on the priority of mouseover, in `Chrome` that is.

What happens is, in `Chrome`, at the point where the two elements overlap the left-most element seems to always react to the `mouseover`, and also doesn't visually appear above the other element, where it should, because of the changed `z-index`. In `Firefox` this is no problem however.

I can't find anything about `z-index` in the `bootstrap.css` files. But again, `Firefox` doesn't mind.

I've also tried to apply the `z-index` via class in a `.css` file, but no difference.

Any idea why Chrome won't budge?

Comment: We need more code, about the generated HTML and their CSS styles. A fiddle would be awesome. Now I can only guess it can be related with the `position` attribute, is it absolute? fixed?

Comment: Tried with relative, absolute and fixed. Doesn't change, and messes up my code as well. Maybe I'll fiddle it when I have time.